# databinding datagridview comboboxcolumn and textbox

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

Hello i am trying to do databinding, i have a list of object in Form1 class that I want to bind to a datagrid view it looks like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

   public BindingList<PrefixDataAffichable> prefixepresent { get; set; }

   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      prefixepresent = new BindingList<PrefixDataAffichable>();
      LoadData();
      dataGridView1.DataSource = prefixepresent;
    }


}
```

and the  PrefixDataAffichable class looks like

```
public class PrefixDataAffichable
{
    public string PrfixeInstance { get; set; }
    public BindingList<string> PrfixePossibleChoice { get; set; }
    public string PrefixeDescription { get; set; }

    BindingList<string> PrfixePoPrfixeInstancessibleChoice = new BindingList<string>();

    public PrefixDataAffichable(PrefixRef prefixref)
    {
        PrefixeDescription = prefixref.prefix._description;
        PrfixeInstance = prefixref.prefix._prefixe + "(" + prefixref.texteentreparanthese + ")";
        PrfixePossibleChoice.Add(_PrfixeInstance);
        PrfixePossibleChoice.Add(_PrfixeInstance + "1!");

    }

}
```

when I do the databinding the 2 column appear as textboxcolumn but i can't make the combo box column apppear. I tired to create it manually and put  the DataPropertyName manully to: PrfixePossibleChoice But programm craches when it runs.

Do any one know how to make the column appear when i select the class as the data binding source or how to add the column by code;

**Update** : I added the code

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = prefixepresent;
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colbox.DataPropertyName = "PrfixePossibleChoice";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colbox);
```

the error is : System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Comment: What error do you get? And how you (post code) tried to bind the combobox column manually using DataPropertyName

Comment: @Junaith I updated the question I hope it is clearer and that someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DataSource` for the combobox column while you are binding it. You are getting the error because the value being set for the combobox cell is not available in the combobox column's `DataSource` or `Items` collection.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = prefixepresent;
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colbox.DataPropertyName = "PrfixePossibleChoice";
colbox.DataSource = set the datasource here
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colbox);
```